# Ways to add video to a website using code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I recently began coding my first webpages and it's lots of fun.
Currently I have a project which requires me to add a video to a certain section of the webpage. The problem is that I have never done that before and I'm absolutely clueless as to how to add a video by means of coding. Could somebody be so kind to introduce me to some ways to accomplish this?

In case it is relevant
I am trying to build a One-page website and I'm using the following languages: html, css & javascript

Comment: The basic tutorial for starting: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/

Comment: Check out html5 videos, or embed from youtube

Comment: U can find a dozen tutorials everywhere for e.x: [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful replies! I found a solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take examples from this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

It depends on the format and where the video is hosted. That page provides some examples, one is:

```
<video src="videofile.webm" autoplay poster="posterimage.jpg">
Sorry, your browser doesn't support embedded videos, 
but don't worry, you can <a href="videofile.webm">download it</a>
and watch it with your favorite video player!
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a static video, just use a [Video Tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video) and set its source to whatever video you want.

If it's some dynamic video, you can use javascript to set the `src` element of the video tag after it has loaded.

If it's not a video that exists online, you can use an `input` as well as [The object api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) to set the source of the video tag.